# Basic Authentication with WebAPI and HTML/JS Client?

Tags: web-application, authentication, rest

I just purchased Badri L's Pro ASP.NET Web API Security in an attempt to learn the least-expensive means to securing my WebAPI, in terms of time-to-implement.  I have zero experience with security and am looking for a solution that is "good enough" to get the app usable without sending plaintext over the wire.

The app is built on .NET Web API and serves JSON to HTML/JS SPA clients.  Eventually the clients will require their own API keys.

For now, I need to allow users to securely login and register using a username/password from these clients.

I began to implement Basic Authentication per Chapter 8 "Knowledge Factors" in the above mentioned book because of the simplicity, however it seems like this forces the clients to use a browser dialog to collect credentials, instead of collecting from a form.

Is there any way to get around this and use a form?  If not, what would you suggest as an alternative security solution?

I was considering Forms Authentication but I'm not sure what the pros/cons are in the context of WebAPI; there's no mention of it in the book.

Comment: Don't it explain how the SSL works ?

Comment: Does it help? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/forms-based-authentication. Quick search on Google but that seems like examples in your domain.. (I'm not a .NET expert at all). You basically have to prepare some login page that perform the Baisc Auth part against a server (under-the-hood) more than preferably through TLS.

Answer (score 2):

The data which is sent on the wire is not usually programmers' work and it doesn't happen in the program layer, it happens in the transferring time. You could enable SSL on the web server to send and receive encrypted data.